# Having problems to copy strings, when opening file

Tags: c, file

**Explanation of program:** So I got a file called "file.txt", and two pointers to the same file, f1 and f2.

I want to do some changes to `file.txt` when flag = 1 , and other changes when flag  = 0.

**More specificly:** (if flag=1, change diagonal of matrix with second column, if flag=0 change diagonal values of matrix with second line).

**Problem:** I get run-time error when copying strings in this line:
`strcpy(ch_data_temp, ch_data1);` (The error says that there are invalid values in `ch_data1`)

**How file looks like:** `file.txt`

```
001002003
004005006
007008009
```

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void func(FILE *f_1, FILE *f_2, int flag);

void main()
{
    int flag = 1;
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    f1 = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    if (f1 == NULL)
        printf("problem");
    f2 = f1;
    func(f1, f2, flag);

}

void func(FILE *f_1, FILE *f_2, int flag)
{
    char ch_data_temp[4], ch_data1[4], ch_data2[4];
    int i, d;

    fseek(f_1, 0, SEEK_END);
    d = ftell(f_1) / 3;
    d = sqrt(d);
    fseek(f_1, 0, SEEK_SET);

    if (flag == 1)
        fseek(f_2, 3 * (d / 2), SEEK_SET);
    if (flag == 0)
        fseek(f_2, 3 * d*(d / 2), SEEK_SET);

    for (i = 0; i<d; i++)
    {
        fgets(ch_data1, 4, f_1);
        fgets(ch_data2, 4, f_2);

        strcpy(ch_data_temp, ch_data1);
        strcpy(ch_data1, ch_data2);
        strcpy(ch_data2, ch_data_temp);

        fseek(f_1, -3, SEEK_CUR);
        fputs(ch_data1, f_1);
        fseek(f_2, -3, SEEK_CUR);
        fputs(ch_data2, f_2);

        fseek(f_1, 3 * d, SEEK_CUR);
        if (flag == 1)
            fseek(f_2, 3 * (d - 1), SEEK_CUR);
        if (flag == 0)
            fseek(f_2, 0, SEEK_CUR);

    }
}
```

Comment: Copy the exact error message into your question.

Comment: `flag` is never `0`. And because of `f2 = f1;`, in `func()` there is no difference between `f_1` and `f_2`. You opened the file only once and anything you operate on `f_1` also happens on `f_2` because they are just two names for the same object.

Comment: Please show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The lines of your file are 8 bytes long but your read the lines (using `fgets`) into a 4 byte buffer. You buffer needs to be at least 10 bytes long (8 bytes for the characters, 1 byte for the `\n` and one byte for the zero terminator. There may be more issues though,

Comment: The string 001002003 is nine bytes, not eight.

Comment: @Ilan.. It's a little bit confusing.. Can you add how the output should look like in question details?

Comment: @FredK `"001002003"` is a line of text in a file and certainly consists of 8 characters and an end-of-line character(s).  From a C library standpoint, it is not a _string_.  For `fgets()` to read that line of text completely takes `char buf[10]` in which will be stored the _string_ "001002003\n": that is 10 `char` as it includes the 8 printable characters, _new line_ and a terminating null character.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `f_1 = f_2`, since `f_1` is a `FILE*` and `f_2` too, they will be affected in the same way since it is the same pointer.  When you use `fseek()` on `f_2`, it is exactly the same as using it on `f_1` and vice-versa.  The problem is that you don't really know what you're reading and then you can't be sure of what is inside `ch_data1`.

In the same way, doing `fgets(ch_data2, 4, f_2);` is exactly like doing `fgets(ch_data2, 4, f_1);`